# Can you determine a differential equation from its solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A linear first-order differential equation has two solutions:
>   $$y_1(x)=x^2 \\y_2(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$ Determine the differential
>   equation

I did some research and I think I can use the wronskian to determine my original DE but I dont' really get how it works. Can someone show me how it's done? (It would be nice if you could use a different example so I can solve this question myself).

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure. Can this diff. equation have only one solution? I just checked the question again and I copied it correctly. Our other worksheets have been full of mistakes too so I wouldn't be surprised if this is another mistake

Comment: A first order equation has an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @copper.hat The differential equation $y'=y$ has infinitely many solutions and is first order...

Comment: @Tom-Tom: I meant linearly independent, since it is linear any multiple will do, of course. In any case, Julian has given a nice answer below. I was incorrectly assuming uniqueness (as implied by some Lipschitz condition, for example).

Comment: Uniqueness results include an initial condition.

Comment: Congratulations for your last sentence !

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: Fuzzy thinking on my part. I was wondering how two solutions could pass through $y=1,x=1$. However $x=1$ is not in the domain of any solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let $y'=a(x)\,y+f(x)$ be the equation. We have to determine $a$ and $f$. The function $y_1-y_2$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $y'=a\,y$, that is
$$
2\,x+\frac{1}{x^2}=a(x)\Bigl(x^2-\frac1x\Bigr).
$$
From this you find $a$, and then $f$.

$$$$$$$$

Comment: this is the way

Comment: Cool. Looks so easy, but how did you know that $y_1-y_2$ is a soltuion. Is there some sort of "rule" that says that any linear combination of solutions is also a solution?

Comment: Very nice solution ! (+1) Just note that the left-hand side should be $2x+\frac1{x^2}$.

Comment: @bluemoon, subtract $y_2' = a y_2 + f$ from $y_1' = a y_1 + f$

Comment: following Vargas's advice  you get  $(y_1-y_2)'=a*(y_1-y_2)$ where $y_1-y_2$ fits the homogeneous form of the equation. (without $f(x)$)

Comment: Yes. You can find $a$ and $f$ in terms of $y_1$ and $y_2$:$$a=\frac{y_1'-y_2'}{y_1-y_2}.$$ I leave to you to find the expression for $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a nice evening.

Comment: @bluemoon yes, the rule is linearity of the derivative operator. It basically works because $(f + g)' = f' + g'$.

Answer (score 4):

In case of finding the linear **second order** differential equation for which $\{y_1,y_2\}$ is the basis of solutions, you can follow your first intuition and solve it using the Wronskian.

First you have to check that $W(y_1,y_2)(x) \ne 0$ for any $x$ on the interval definition of your differential equation.
Hopefully, $\forall x >0 $ or $x<0$ :
$$W(y_1,y_2)(x) =
 \begin{vmatrix}
   y_1 & y_2 \\
   y_1' & y_2' 
\end{vmatrix} 
 =
 \begin{vmatrix}
   x^2 & x^{-1} \\
   2x & -x^{-2}  
\end{vmatrix}  = - 3 \ne 0$$

That means that the following equation

$$  \begin{vmatrix}
  y & y_1 & y_2 \\
   y' & y_1' & y_2' \\  
y'' & y_1'' & y_2''
\end{vmatrix} = 0 = y''  \begin{vmatrix}
   y_1 & y_2 \\
   y_1' & y_2' 
\end{vmatrix} -y'  \begin{vmatrix}
   y_1 & y_2 \\
   y_1'' & y_2'' 
\end{vmatrix} + y  \begin{vmatrix}
   y_1' & y_2' \\
   y_1'' & y_2'' 
\end{vmatrix}  $$

is a true second order differential equation. And you can see that both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solution to this equation by replacing $y$ by $y_1$ or $y_2$ in the determinant expression.

Comment: 1st order $\subset$ 2nd order..., the highest coefficient=0, implyin that any linear function is a solution of the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternatively**:

As the equation is linear, $y=ax^2+(1-a)\dfrac1x$ is a one-parameter general solution, which includes $y_1$ and $y_2$. Eliminate $a$ from the system

$$y=ax^2+\frac{1-a}x\\
y'=2ax-\frac{1-a}{x^2}.$$

You get

$$a=\frac{xy'+y}{3x^2},$$ hence

$$y=\frac{xy'+y}{3x^2}(x^2-\frac1x)+\frac1x.$$